# Rblpapi get securities from a CSV rows

Tags: r, csv, bloomberg, read.csv, rblpapi

I want to use the rows of a CSV file to populate the security id's (commodities futures) required for bdp function..any ideas? Can Rblpapi support this?

```
px <- bdp(securities = c("BOH8 Comdty","CLH8 Comdty","GCZ8 Comdty","NGU18 Comdty","LAU18 Comdty"),
              fields = c("PX_LAST","DS002","PR070","PR067","PR064","HT006"))
```

Comment: So your question is: how to read a csv file and pass the content to the `securities` property?

Comment: i manually typed the securities into the code above ("BOH8 Comdty","CLH8 Comdty") etc...i want to automate that with a csv file. i might 500+ securities

Comment: So your question is really about importing CSV data into an array in R rather than a Bloomberg question. You may want to delete this question and create a new one where you explain what your CSV file looks like and that you want the content into a variable. Although there's a high chance that's it's been asked before: a Google search on this may help you.